# How do you change a class when a button is clicked in Svelte?

Tags: class, button, binding, svelte

How do you change a class when a button is clicked in Svelte?

The code is here:

```
<script lang="ts">
  let rank = 1;

  const changeRank = () => {
    if (rank == 1) {
        rank = 2
    } else {
        rank = 1
    }
  };
</script>

<main>
    <div class="card" class:input-focus={rank === 1? "rank-1" : "rank-2"} />
    <button on:click={changeRank}>Change Rank</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class directive (`class:...`), this will add the class after the `:` if the value is truthy. This is probably not what you want here, because both values are truthy so it will always add the class `input-focus`.

You probably meant to do something like this:

```html
<div class="card {rank === 1 ? 'rank-1' : 'rank-2'}" />
```

If all classes have that prefix you could just do this as well:

```html
<div class="card rank-{rank}" />
```